# How to align a legend relative to a GridSpec cell?

Tags: matplotlib

I am creating a figure like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7, 8))
outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios = [2, 1])
inner_grid1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(4, 3, subplot_spec=outer_grid[0])
inner_grid2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 3, subplot_spec=outer_grid[1])
```

Now I would like to have one legend for all plots in `inner_grid1` and a separate legend for all plots in `inner_grid2`. And I would like those legends to be placed nicely, even though they are higher than a single plot, and cannot have more than one column to not make the figure too wide.

Here is an example where I tried to align the legends with trial and error with method 2 below, however this took ages to make.
[image: Example]

So I see three options to achieve this, none of which work:

1. Place the legend as part of an `Axes` object, but manually move it outside of the actual plot using `axes.legend([...], bbox_to_anchor=(x, y))`. This does not work when the legend is higher as a single plot, because it rescales the plots to fit the legend into its grid cell.
2. Place the legend globally on the `Figure` object. This works, but makes the correct placement really hard. I cannot use `loc = "center right"`, since it centers it for the full figure instead of just the `inner_grid1` or `inner_grid2` plots.
3. Place the legend locally on the `GridSpecFromSubplotSpec` object. This would be perfect. However there is no method to create a legend on a `GridSpecFromSubplotSpec` or related classes, and the `pyplot.legend` method misses parameters to restrict the `loc` to parts of a grid.

Is there a way to place a legend as described?

**As requested, a small code example generating something similar as desired.**
This example uses method 2:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd, seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

GENOMES = ["spneumoniae", "ecoliK12", "scerevisiae", "celegans", "bmori", "hg38"]

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7, 8))
outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios = [2, 1])
inner_grid1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(4, 3, subplot_spec=outer_grid[0])
inner_grid2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 3, subplot_spec=outer_grid[1])

# plots are in sets of six, 2 rows by 3 columns each
for index, genome in enumerate(GENOMES):
    data = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], "y": [1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2], "hue": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"]})

    # first set of six
    ax1 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid1[index])
    ax1 = sns.lineplot(data = data, x = "x", y = "y", hue = "hue", ax = ax1)
    ax1.set_xlabel("")
    ax1.set_ylabel("")
    if index == 2:
        ax1.legend()
        handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
        fig.legend(handles, labels, loc = "center left", title = "", bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 2/3 - 0.03))
    ax1.legend([], [], loc = "lower center", title = f"{genome}")
    fig.add_subplot(ax1)

    # second set of six
    ax2 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid1[index + 6])
    ax2 = sns.lineplot(data = data, x = "x", y = "y", hue = "hue", ax = ax2)
    ax2.set_xlabel("")
    ax2.set_ylabel("")
    ax2.legend([], [], loc = "upper center", title = f"{genome}")
    fig.add_subplot(ax2)

    #third set of six
    ax3 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid2[index])
    ax3 = sns.lineplot(data = data, x = "x", y = "y", hue = "hue", ax = ax3)
    ax3.set_xlabel("")
    ax3.set_ylabel("")
    if index == 2:
        ax3.legend(["#unitigs", "avg. unitig len."])
        handles, labels = ax3.get_legend_handles_labels()
        fig.legend(handles, labels, loc = "center left", title = "", bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 1/6 + 0.05))
    ax3.legend([], [], loc = "upper center", title = f"{genome}")
    fig.add_subplot(ax3)

plt.savefig("stackoverflow_test.pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a copy-and-pasteable reproducible example so we can easily reproduce the problem

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I added and example. It looks rather different from the figure, as I tried to make it as short as possible.